# Bebop States publishing at 5Hz

Tags: ros, bebop-autonomy, parrot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The driver is publishing the states at 5 Hz, is it possible to increase this frequency ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247051/bebop-states-publishing-at-5hz/) by [lexanded](https://answers.ros.org/users/28417/lexanded/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-11-02**:
You can subscribe to Bebop states and make a new publisher that sends the states at faster than 5 Hz, but you would be sending the same state multiple times in between successive reads. [Currently](http://bebop-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reading.html#states-aka-navdata) limited to 5 Hz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the moment the state publishing rate is limited to 5Hz by the firmware.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2